# docker toolbox windows 10 - Docker Quickstart Terminal doesnt work

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I work on windows 10 home.

When i run docker quick start terminal shortcut or run start.sh directly, i get message:

> Docker Machine is not installed. Please re-run the Toolbox Installer
>   and try again. Looks like something went wrong in step ´Looking for
>   vboxmanage.exe´... Press any key to continue...

I tried reinstalling with all options selected, including NDIS5 driver, but i didnt helped. Kinematic works fine, but i cant run docker in terminal.

I checked PATH enviromental variable and there is `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox` there. 
I also checked if git for windows doesnt change working dir when running script, and it doesnt.

Comment: think you need windows 10 professional for docker to work as it needs to access your hyper v.. could be wrong

Comment: Docker itself doe work using Kinematic. Its just quick start terminal that doesnt works. I cant run docker trough console.

Answer (score 3):

Try reinstall the VirtualBox, choosing **repair** mode. **C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\installers\virtualbox** -> **virtualbox.exe** enter. After finished the process, restart you machine and smile!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to edit the shortcut to resolve the issue with bash.exe.

try:

> Right-click on the shortcut
>
> Select Properties
>
> Edit the Target field to point to the location of bash.exe ex. C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh"
>
> Click OK

Comment: I changed shortcut and now its "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i "C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh". It didnt helped. I also tried to run bash exe and run start.sh from there and it also didnt worked.

Comment: thats me out of ideas for this one.. with little information its pretty hard to work out what is wrong.