# lost docker-quickstart folder in wsl2 ubuntu

Tags: docker, cloudera

I installed docker and cloudera/quickstart like this:

1. install and set wsl2 as default
2. install docker desktop
3. change dir of images docker to another dir follow this link:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425898/docker-toolbox-windows-10-docker-quickstart-terminal-doesnt-work)
4. change dir of wsl to another dir follow this link [link](https://grishagin.com/ubuntu/2020/10/26/change-wsl2-container-location.html)
5. open powershell as admin, pull cloudera/quickstart:latest
6. follow this yt video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=elXTmZbNNmE) . in step 5, I can't find folder docker-quickstart. how can I find it now?
   [image]